# Adventure with infinite series, a curiosity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

It is easily verifiable that
$$\sum_{k\geq0}\binom{2k}k\frac1{2^{3k}}=\sqrt{2}.$$
It is not that difficult to get
$$\sum_{k\geq0}\binom{4k}{2k}\frac1{2^{5k}}=\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}+\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}2.$$

> **Question.** Is there something similarly "nice" in computing
>   $$\sum_{k\geq0}\binom{8k}{4k}\frac1{2^{10k}}=?$$
>   Perhaps the same question about
>   $$\sum_{k\geq0}\binom{16k}{8k}\frac1{2^{20k}}=?$$

**NOTE.** The powers of $2$ are selected with a hope (suspicion) for some pattern.

Comment: I don't see how $3$ fits the pattern in $3,5,10,20,...$.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is moderately nice, I would say. We have $\sum \binom{2k}k x^k=(1-4x)^{-1/2}$ for $|x|<1/4$. If we need only terms with $k$ divisible by 4 and $x=2^{-5/2}$, $4x=2^{-1/2}$, we get $$\sum \binom{8k}{4k}2^{-10k}=\frac14\sum_{w^4=1}(1-w/\sqrt{2})^{-1/2}$$
and so on.

Answer (score 12):

More generally, it seems that
$$
\sum_{k\ge0}\binom{2^{j+1}k}{2^jk}2^{-a_{j+2} k}=2^{-j}\sum_{w^{2^j}=1}(1-w/\sqrt2)^{-1/2}
$$
where $a_1=2,a_2=3,a_{j+1}=a_j+a_{j-1}+\dots+a_1$ (cf. [A257113](https://oeis.org/A257113)).

Comment: Note: this has been confirmed up to $j=7$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$f(x):=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{2k}{k}x^k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$$
with $|x|<1/4$. We have for $N,j\in\mathbb{Z}_+$,
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{r=1}^Ne(-{jr}/{N})f\left(xe({r}/{N})\right)&=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{r=1}^Ne(-{jr}/{N})\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{2k}{k}x^ke({kr}/{N})\\
&=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{2k}{k}x^k\frac{1}{N}\sum_{r=1}^Ne({(k-j)r}/{N}),
\end{align}
where $e(x):=e^{2\pi{\rm i}x}$. Hence clearly,
$$\sum_{\substack{k\ge 0\\ k\equiv j\pmod N}}\binom{2k}{k}x^k=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{r=1}^N\frac{e(-{jr}/{N})}{\sqrt{1-4xe(r/N)}},$$
holds for all $N,j\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, which is a more general result.

Comment: Well I would say under the "and so on" at the end of another answer is most probably understood (more or less an equivalent of) this more general formula.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes, you are right. The above is just a very usual and basic technique.

Answer (score 0):

*Mathematica* says, for the first:

$$\,
   _4F_3\left(\frac{1}{8},\frac{3}{8},\frac{5}{8},\frac{7}{8};\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{
   3}{4};\frac{1}{4}\right)$$

and

$$\,
   _8F_7\left(\frac{1}{16},\frac{3}{16},\frac{5}{16},\frac{7}{16},\frac{9}{16},\frac{11}{16}
   ,\frac{13}{16},\frac{15}{16};\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{8},\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{8},
   \frac{3}{4},\frac{7}{8};\frac{1}{16}\right)
$$ for the second.

Comment: What's with the downvotes?

Comment: Is the answer wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong, but I think this is obvious from the definition of the generalized hypergeometric function ${}_pF_q$, and doesn't seem to be a helpful step toward a closed form. (I didn't downvote, fwiw.)

Comment: @DavidZhang Interestingly, for the first two cases, mathematica gives non-hypereometric forms.